# Database Design to handle newsfeed for different activities

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am going to create a new project, where I need users to view their friends activities and actions just like Facebook and LinkedIn.

Each user is allowed to do 5 different types of activities, each activity have different attributes, for example activity X can be public/private for while activity Y will be assigned to categories. Some of actions include 1 users others have 2 or 3 ...etc. Eventually I have to aggregate all these 5 different types of activities on the news feed page.

How can I design a database that is efficient?

I have 3 designs in mind, please let me know your thoughts. Any new ideas will be greatly appreciated!

**1- Separate tables:** since there are nearly 3-4 different columns for each activity, it would be logical to separate each activity to its own table.
**Pros:** Clean database, and easy to develop.
**Cons:** It will need to query the database 5 times and aggregate results to make a single newsfeed page.

**2- One big table:** This table will hold all activities with many unused columns. A new numeric column will be added called "type" which will indicate the type of activity. Some attributes could be combined in an HStore field (since we are using Postgres), others will be queried a lot so I dont think it is a good thing to include them as in an HStore field.
**Pros:** Easy to pull  newsfeed.
**Cons:** Lots of read/writes on the same table, the code will be a bit messier so is the database.

**3- Hybrid:** A solution would be to make one table containing all the newsfeed, with a polymorphic association to other tables that contain details of each specific activity.
**Pros:** Tidy code and database, easy to add new activities.
**Cons:** JOIN ALL THE TABLES to make a single newsfeed! Still better than making 5 different queries.

As I am writing this post I am starting to lean towards solution number 2. Please advise!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a graph database for this. [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org). It will add very flexible attributes on either nodes (users) or links (types of relations).

For small sets and few joins, SQL databases are faster and more appropriate. But if your starting point is 5 table joins, graph databases seem simpler and offer similar performance (if not better).

Comment: Can you use AGE extension on Postgres to accomplish the same.